# Meteor: Oauth1.0a login service for OSM

Tags: javascript, oauth, meteor, openstreetmap

I'm trying to implement a account login service for Meteor from the OpenStreetMap project (Oauth 1.0a).

Meteor has a lot of packages for oauth:
accounts-oauth-helper
accounts-oauth
accounts-oauth1-helper
accounts-oauth2-helper
oauth-encryption
oauth
oauth1
oauth2

Which package could I use as base for implementing a oauth service? The packages I found on Atmosphere were mostly for oauth2 or specific apis. Any suggestions for a good 1.0a example?
Is it right that accounts-ui generates configuration options for oauth services?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `twitter` + `accounts-twitter` packages are an example of the oauth1 authentication flow, as can be seen from the "1" parameter in the service registration: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/twitter/twitter_server.js#L14